# How to search multiple directories and delete specific file types in those directories?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to search all directories below the batch file for any folders called `History` and then delete all *.zip files in those directories.

I have a batch file that currently deletes all files with 2 numbers and a $ symbol using the following code:

```
For /F "delims=" %%A in (
  'Dir /B/S "*,*" ^| findstr ",[0-9][0-9]*$" '
) Do Del "%%A"
```

But what about all zip files that are ONLY in a `History` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command line could be used in a batch file to delete all *.zip files in all directories with name `History` found in current directory and its subdirectories:

```
@for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir History /AD /B /S 2^>nul') do @del /A /F /Q "%%I\*.zip" 2>nul
```

The command **FOR** starts one more command process in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line specified between the two `'` which results in execution of the following command line on Windows being installed in `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir History /AD /B /S 2>nul
```

The background Windows command process runs internal command **DIR** which

- searches in current directory and all its subdirectories because of option `/S`
- only for directories because of option `/AD` (attribute directory)
- with a name matching the string `History` and
- outputs the found directories in bare format because of option `/B` line by line which means just the names of the found directories with full path because of option `/S` to handle **STDOUT** of the background command process.

The full qualified directory names are output by **DIR** never enclosed in double quotes even on containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` which require the usage of double quotes around full qualified name on passing it as argument string to a command or application.

It is possible that **DIR** cannot find any directory matching the search criteria in file system. In this case **DIR** outputs to handle **STDERR** of background command process an error message which is a bit confusing for a reader because it contains the word `file` and not the word `directory` or `folder`. This error message on no directory `History` found by **DIR** is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** with option `/F` processes the captured output written to handle **STDOUT** of background command process line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself. The text output to handle **STDERR** of background command process is redirected by **FOR** to handle **STDERR** of current command process which is processing the batch file and would be displayed in the console window on running this batch file without `2^>nul`.

Empty lines are always ignored by **FOR** on processing captured output. But there are no empty lines in this case because of **DIR** outputs either nothing or the found directories with full path line by line with no empty lines between.

**FOR** with option `/F` would split up a line by default into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab characters as string delimiters and would assign just first space/tab delimited string to loop variable `I`. This string splitting behavior is not wanted here because of path to a `History` directory could contain one or more spaces. For that reason `delims=` specifies an empty list of delimiters which disable line splitting behavior completely and assigned to loop variable `I` is the full qualified directory name as output by **DIR**.

**FOR** with option `/F` would ignore also the current line if the first substring starts after line splitting with a semicolon because of `eol=;` is the default for end of line option. This default can be kept here because of a full qualified directory name starts either with a drive letter or with a backslash (UNC path) and therefore starts definitely never with a semicolon. So every directory name output with full path by **DIR** is processed by **FOR** and assigned without any modification one after the other to loop variable `I`.

The command **DEL** is executed for each full qualified directory name assigned to loop variable `I` never enclosed in double quotes to delete all files matching the wildcard pattern `*.zip` in this directory. The full qualified directory name concatenated with the string `\*.zip` must be enclosed in double quotes to be correct passed to command **DEL** on containing a space or another character special interpreted by Windows command processor.

The **DEL** option `/A` is used to override default `/A-H` to delete also ZIP files with hidden attribute set which otherwise would be ignored by **DEL**.

The **DEL** option `/F` is used to force a deletion of read-only ZIP files.

The **DEL** option `/Q` is used to delete the ZIP files quietly without prompt the user for confirmation.

The command **DEL** could fail to delete ZIP files, for example if a ZIP file to delete is opened currently by another process or if the user has not the required permissions to delete a ZIP file in a specific directory. In this case the command **DEL** would output an error message to handle **STDERR**. Such an error message output by **DEL** is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

The two `@` in the command line just disable output of the **FOR** command line after parsing by Windows command processor before execution and of the **DEL** command line before execution on each iteration of the loop. The two `@` are not needed if the batch file contains at top `@echo off` to disable command line output after parsing before execution for all command lines in batch file.

Help on the three used commands is output on running them with parameter `/?` in a Windows [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, i.e. executing `for /?` and `dir /?` and `del /?`.

See also: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)